# How can Netbeans 8.1 give an error on Derby DB version 10.5 when my DB is version 10.10

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

When running my Java EE project I get an error stating that my Derby DB needs to be version 10.6 or later. When starting the DB however, it says it's version 10.10.

The code generating the error is the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
private Long id;
```

When starting the database, the generated output is:

```
Thu Mar 24 18:58:18 CET 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Thu Mar 24 18:58:19 CET 2016 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

The error output is:

```
Info:   Create fake account
Info:   New user: a a
Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Use of 'NEXT VALUE' requires database to be upgraded from version 10.5 to version 10.6 or later.
Error Code: 30000
Call: VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR MY_ENTITY_SEQ)
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR MY_ENTITY_SEQ)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.select(QuerySequence.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_NoTransaction_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4288)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at business.AccountHandlerBean.addUser(AccountHandlerBean.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy292.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at presentation.AdminServlet.doPost(AdminServlet.java:143)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Use of 'NEXT VALUE' requires database to be upgraded from version 10.5 to version 10.6 or later.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:586)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:992)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Use of 'NEXT VALUE' requires database to be upgraded from version 10.5 to version 10.6 or later.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 104 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Derby **code**, which is contained in jar files in the CLASSPATH of your Derby Network Server, is at version 10.10.

Your Derby **database**, which is rows of data stored in tables in operating system files in a folder on your hard disk, is at version 10.5.

To upgrade your Derby database to match the version of your Derby code, you need to connect to your Derby database once, using the Derby version 10.10 code, with the special Derby JDBC Connection URL:

```
jdbc:derby://my-network-server-address/path/to/my/db;upgrade=true
```

For more information, check these docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevupgrades.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would've taken me ages to figure that out by myself.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I downloaded the latest JDK to try use derby that comes with that.  Didn't work.  Then I downloaded derby 10.13.1.1 direct from derby website, extracted it and pointed Netbeans Java DB (in services window) to it.  Using derbyclient jar dependency v10.13.1.1 in maven as well in my client code.  No idea why it's not working.  I've no reference at all to an older version of derby.

ps. tried connecting using the upgrade url above in persistence unit and through ij command line tool.  No luck.

Comment: Well, what is the error you get? Instead of trying to open a new topic as a comment on an existing discussion, consider posting a new question with your full details and particulars.